# what is difference between useradd -m and useradd -d?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I want to know where should I use `useradd -m` or `useradd -d` to make a new home directory? I didn't get the purpose of `-m` and `-d` flag in `useradd`?

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to assume you read the manual (`man useradd`), which says

> **`-d`, `--home HOME_DIR`** The new user will be created using `HOME_DIR` as the value for the user's login directory [...]

and

> **`-m`, `--create-home`** Create the user's home directory if it does not exist [...]

As it says, the `--home` flag defines the entry in the user database (`/etc/passwd`) and `--create-home` creates the directory.

In a typical single user home environment you'd probably want the `--create-home` flag (`-m` if you prefer), leaving the other at its default value.